# HTML Form: Submit button activated upon enter

Tags: html, forms

I have a confirm form with two submit buttons: delete and cancel. I'd like for delete to be the default choice, which is activated upon clicking enter. However, neither button is active per default.

I can do something in js, but I really thought that this was default form behavior. Also, there should be an indication of which button is the active one. I'm trying in Chrome.

http://jsfiddle.net/wqDtg/

```
 <form action = "delete/" id = "the_form"  method = "post">

     <input type = "hidden" name = "the_id" value = "123"></input>
     <input type = "submit" value = "Delete" ></input>
     <input type = "submit" value = "Cancel"  onclick="$('#the_form').addClass('hidden');return false;" ></input>

 </form>
```

Comment: Why'd you want to do that??? I can't think of a scenario where this wouldn't be unintuitive.

Comment: @OdraEncoded — "Yes, do the thing I asked you to do" is the default in most confirm dialogs.

Comment: Which, is what I want!!

Answer (score 1):

Unless you add JavaScript, a form will only be submitted by pressing Enter if a form control inside it has the focus. If the focus is on a button, that button will trigger the form submission. If it is on another input, then it will trigger the first submit button.

Give the delete button the focus using the [`autofocus` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#autofocusing-a-form-control%3a-the-autofocus-attribute)

Comment: this works in the jsfiddle example, but not in my real-life code. Not sure why. Will look at it. Thanks.